# Suppress on condition on crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have multiple Images on my reports(image1, image2...), but I want to show image1 when I am doing report 1a. All other data on the report remains the same, it is just the image that needs to change. I do not want to create multiple reports as there are too many images and my report uses sub-reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create multiple copies for the same report then for each copy provide the title name in

```
File---> Summary Info --> Title
```

Now write the supress condition on your image as:

```
if ReportTitle = "abc"
then true
else false
```

Comment: @sifisonkalitshana if its worked accept as answer... so that others can use.